# Why are my links not working in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, html, zurb-foundation

Now, I'm not new to code. At all. However, I'm dumbfounded what could be going wrong.

If you navigate to this site: https://clickitsocial.net

The buttons/links on the home page work.

However, navigate over to the Portfolio page: https://clickitsocial.net/portfolio

None of the links on the flip cards work when I try to click on them, and I do have the href attribute set for each link, even if it's a # until I figure out what to put in each one.

Could it be a conflict with jQuery or something? Something else?

I'm using WordPress v4.8, JointsWP theme, to build from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Liz,

The issue isn't with the hyperlink, but the `.flip-card-inner` div.

If you remove `backface-visibilty: hidden;` from `.flip-card-inner` then it will work.

You only want `backface-visibility: hidden;` to be on the `.flip-card-inner-front` and `.flip-card-inner-back` divs.

Try that and see how it goes.

Ryan

Answer (score 0):

To get the Foundation Flip Card to work correctly on Firefox & Chrome:
https://foundation.zurb.com/building-blocks/blocks/flip-card.html

First, we used Ryan's solution to solve the Chrome issue: remove backface-visibility:hidden from the .flip-card-inner class.

Then we ran into a Firefox (version 63-66.0.1) bug with the backface-visibility property. The workaround is to add: transform: rotateY(0deg) to the .flip-card-inner-front class.

Reference: https://github.com/Fyrd/caniuse/issues/4631